# Confusion with floating point numbers

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-precision, floating-point-conversion

```
int main()
{
  float x=3.4e2;
  printf("%f",x);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
340.000000  // It's ok.
```

But if write `x=3.1234e2` the output is `312.339996` and if `x=3.12345678e2` the output is `312.345673`.

Why are the outputs like these? I think if I write `x=3.1234e2` the output should be `312.340000`, but the actual output is `312.339996` using GCC compiler.

Comment: have a look at : http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not all fractional numbers have an exact binary equivalent so it is rounded to the nearest value.

Simplified example,

if you have 3 bits for the fraction, you can have:

```
0
0.125
0.25
0.375
...
```

0.5 has an exact representation, but 0.1 will be shown as 0.125.

Of course the real differences are much smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point numbers are normally represented as binary fractions times a power of two, for efficiency.  This is about as accurate as base-10 representation, except that there are decimal fractions that cannot be exactly represented as binary fractions.  They are, instead, represented as approximations.

Moreover, a `float` is normally 32 bits long, which means that it doesn't have all that many significant digits.  You can see in your examples that they're accurate to about 8 significant digits.

You are, however, printing the numbers to slightly beyond their significance, and therefore you're seeing the difference.  Look at your `printf` format string documentation to see how to print fewer digits.

You may need to represent decimal numbers exactly; this often happens in financial applications.  In that case, you need to use a special library to represent numbers, or simply calculate everything as integers (such as representing amounts as cents rather than as dollars and fractions of a dollar).

The standard reference is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), but it looks like that would be very advanced for you.  Alternatively, you could Google floating-point formats (particularly IEEE standard formats) or look them up on Wikipedia, if you wanted the details.