# Php and floating numbers

Tags: php

I have this example

```
$x = 0.154 + 0.408;
$y = 0.562;
echo $x - $y;
```

You would think it's 0 but it's not ( well maybe it depends on your system and php version ).
Anyway for those who don't see 0, what's the correct way to do float operations ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.bc.php

Comment: You might want to read "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic". (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for the full gory details.

Comment: 100500th question of the kind and nobody cares to search first

Comment: @Col - You forgot some 000's i think :-) but maybe if you don't understand the problem, it's difficult to find the right keywords for searching.

Comment: @martinstoeckli for ones who can't, there are similar questions listed right in the form and in the "related" section of this page. With very little effort it is possible to spot the related question among them, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839691/confusion-in-floating-point-numbers go figure.

Comment: Nice video about a problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$x = bcadd (0.154 ,0.408);
$y = 0.562;
echo bcsub($x,$y);
```

Comment: if you have the extra library installed..., and you need the precision at the end

Comment: Since PHP 4.0.4, libbcmath is bundled with PHP. You don't need any external libraries for this extension.

Comment: Sorry for this late warning, but this example is plain wrong, it works for the wrong reasons! If you change 0.562 to 0.1 it will still return 0, because `bcsub()` works with a precision of 0 decimal points. Even worse, `$x` will be 0 in your example. If you would write `bcsub($x,$y,18)` you would have the same problem as with floating point numbers. You cannot solve this problem with a library, you really have to understand floating point arithmetic.

Comment: It's not a wrong.You need just add a "scale".$x = bcadd (0.154 ,0.408,3);
$y = 0.1;
echo bcsub($x,$y,3); It's work.

Comment: @Oyeme - This would indeed solve exactly this problem. But i can easily provide other examples like `10 / 3` where the number is not representable in say 20 digits, and then the problem is there again. Another difficulty is, that you have to define the scale, and how do you detect the scale? Not every calculation is as easy as this addition, use one division and some additions and define the scale... So, never compare two floating point values directly.

Comment: @martinstoeckli yes I agree with you.This solution was for current situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not related to the PHP itself, that's how computers work - some numbers cannot be reprezented precisely so you have to keep in mind that when you work with floats and doubles you work on numbers **approximations**.

You can read more about floating point on Google: [floating point arithmetic](http://www.google.pl/search?aq=0&oq=floating+point+ar&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=floating+point+arithmetic)

Answer (score 0):

You really should understand the problem (there is no library which can magically solve this problem, PHP is all you need).

A very good article you can find here, it's actually written for Delphi, but the problem is not specific to any language: 
[Comparing floating point values](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-floats.html#rounding)

Please also read the warning in the documenation of PHP:
[Floating point precision](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)